# Not able to assign List to IEnumerable Object

Tags: c#, collections

I am trying to assign a list of object to a Property of same type in a loop but I am not able to assign it.

It is coming as null always.

```
public IEnumerable<AppointmentModel> AddProducts (IEnumerable<AppointmentModel> apps)
{
    foreach(var app in apps)
    {
        var products = new List<ProductsEntity>
        {
            new ProductsEntity {Id = "A", Desc = "ABC"},
            new ProductsEntity {Id = "B", Desc = "ABC"},
            new ProductsEntity {Id = "C", Desc = "ABC"}
        }
        app.Products = products; // Values are successfully getting assigned here
    }
    return apps; //apps.FirstOrDefault().Products is Null here
}

public class AppointmentModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<ProductEntity> Products {get;set;}
}
```

I have tried converting my apps to IQueryable and IList also but it is coming null only

Comment: After fixing some typos your code works fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5MUV0M I think your problem is somewhere else...

Comment: Please show where do you get the null and show how you pass data to `AddProducts`. Are you certain that you are not passing an empty collection?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your problem is **deferred** execution. Where does `apps` come from? Since it is not declared as an array or list, I assume that it's _enumerated again and again_ each time you iterate through it, So when you call `FirstOrDefault()` new instances are created.

Comment: Agree with @ChrFin. You code is fine after a few typo's. Are you sure you have items in "apps" that is passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already enumerate apps variable in foreach loop. After loop you try to access first element of it but enumerator already reached end of the list.

If you get elements of it as an array, you won't face with such a problem.

Try this.

```
    public IEnumerable<AppointmentModel> AddProducts(IEnumerable<AppointmentModel> apps)
    {
        var appointmentModels = apps as AppointmentModel[] ?? apps.ToArray();
        foreach (var app in appointmentModels)
        {
            var products = new List<ProductsEntity>
            {
                new ProductsEntity {Id = "A", Desc = "ABC"},
                new ProductsEntity {Id = "B", Desc = "ABC"},
                new ProductsEntity {Id = "C", Desc = "ABC"}
            };
            app.Products = products; // Values are successfully getting assigned here
        }
        return appointmentModels; //apps.FirstOrDefault().Products is Null here
    }
```

Comment: I _guess_ that could solve it (if deferred execution was the reason here). But your answer would be better with some explanation why and how it solves the problem.

Comment: Could you please explain why it worked after converting it to an array ??